# CloudFormation/SAM: How to fix logical resource name

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I have a SAM application which have several lambdas. Each lambda is associated with log group for it.

```yaml
  fooFunc:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      # snip

  FopFuncLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /aws/lambda/${fooFunc}
      RetentionInDays: 365
```

I found typo after deployment: `FopFuncLogGroup` should be `FooFuncLogGroup`.

Question: Can I simply change logical name?

I think just changing logical name deletes and recreates log group.
If so, it is not tolerable.

`"DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"` may fix that, but I think there will be conflict when creating `FooFuncLogGroup` resource then.

`FopFuncLogGroup` is not referenced in anywhere.

Comment: If it is never referenced anywhere, and it's only a typo that is visible in your template, I wouldn't bother. You could probably use the deletionpolicy and then maybe reference it as an already existing resource, but it's probably more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Practically, I wouldn't bother neither. Though I'm curious is there way to reference non-managed resource as an already existing one?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but has huge limitations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html